# System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to translate set operation since both operands have different 'Include' operations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I'm using Entity Framework Core 5 and [Table Per Type feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-type-configuration).
I have `Contractor` entity and two inherited entities: `Company` and `Individual`.
I need to union them.
I'm trying the following code to union them into one collection:

```
    var companies = (from company in _dbContext.Companies
                      .Include(c => c.ShareHolders)
                      .Include(c => c.Director)
                      select company).Cast<Contractor>();
    var individuals = (from individual in _dbContext.Individuals
                      select individual).Cast<Contractor>();
    Contractors = new ObservableCollection<Contractor>(companies.Union(individuals));
```

In DBContext I have the following configuration method:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
            .HasOne(c => c.Director);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Shareholder>()
            .HasOne(s => s.Contractor);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
            .HasMany(c => c.ShareHolders)
            .WithOne(f => f.Company)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
```

Question:

How to get rid of the exception or how to modify my configuration so that shareholders are populated and I could simply use Contractors DbSet instead of manually building union query?

System.InvalidOperationException

Unable to translate set operation since both operands have different 'Include' operations. Consider having same 'Include' applied on both sides.

Stacktrace:

at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.ProcessSetOperation(NavigationExpansionExpression outerSource, MethodInfo genericMethod, NavigationExpansionExpression innerSource)

It fails on the line with .Union().

Previously I had Contractors DbSet in DbContext, but Shareholders collection didn't fill in for company objects. So I rewrote the code as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

You have to divide your query by two queries. Eager Loading cannot handle such `Union` or `Concat` which is preferred in your case.

Short answer why: because no way to generate SQL for such case. If there are identical `Includes` - it is possible because EF can generate joins to subquery with UNION.

```cs
Contractors = new ObservableCollection<Contractor>(
    companies.AsEnumerable()
    .Concat(individuals.AsEnumerable())
);
```

Comment: It works, but it does not look good. Is there there any way to force contractors to populate shareholders and avoid manual union operation?

Comment: Not sure that i get your question. But maybe you have to move ShareHolders to Contractor type?

Comment: No, Shareholder contains 2 fields share (percent) and contractor. The question is. How to specify specific includes for inherited objects when Table per type is used and base class collection is used.

Comment: Company is connected to shareholders as one to many and specific to company.(not availble in individual)

Comment: @AccessDenied, I think there is no way. Only two queries. Eager Loading is very complicated functionality and it cannot handle such case.

Answer (score 0):

got the same issue, it seems like EF 6 supports it, but not the .NET Core 5. There is a note under the title [Table-per-type configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-type-configuration)
So you can move to EF 6 or write SQL stored procedures.

Also you need to check if your Union operation unites the same models.